# Winforms controls won't display

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm calling a Winforms window from within another winforms object (supposed to be a simple Loading window), but when the window.Show() is called, All I see is this:
[image]

The top space is supposed to be a label with the "waiting" text, and the bottom is supposed to be an animated GIF.  I have stepped through to verify that InitializeComponent() is called for this object.  Here is the code that calls it:

```
        LoadWindow loading = new LoadWindow();
        loading.Show();
        loading.BringToFront();

        //Perform loading function in background worker
        //BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        //worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        //worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        // Close the loading window
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        loading.Close();
```

The pause is there for debugging purposes at the moment, and as you can see the background worker is not running for now while I try to figure this out.  Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get this window to display properly?

Comment: And what if you remove Sleep() ?

Comment: Can you please post your code how it looks with that `BackgroundWorker`. And also post the `worker_DoWork`-Method

Comment: Try to remove `Sleep()` and make a call of `Close()` from `worker_DoWork` via `loading`'s `BeginInvoke()`

Comment: Adding loading.Update(); is a hack to work around this.  Don't put the UI thread to sleep.

Comment: `loading.Show()` run in thread?

Comment: I suggest use splash screen instead of editing the `InitializeComponent()` *-"Sometimes shotgun surgery is ugly"*

Comment: Sorry for the lack of responsiveness on my part!  I ended up being gone for a few days unexpectedly, my bad.  al_amanat's and TomTom were correct about the Thread.Sleep, I removed that and put the close function in a RunWorkerCompleted function and it works like a champ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You freezes your UI Thread by `Thread.Sleep()` call. So controls can't invalidate its layout.
And I guess than call of `loading.Close()` had to be in `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted` event.

```
private void Show()
{
    LoadWindow loading = new LoadWindow();
    loading.Show();
    loading.BringToFront();

    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
        (s, e) => 
        {
            // your logic
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        });
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s, e) =>
        {
            loading.Close();
        });
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is the call of `Thread.Sleep(10000)` in the UI-Thread.

A possible solution for this would be:

```
public void LoadSomething()
{
 LoadWindow loading = new LoadWindow();
 loading.Show();
 loading.BringToFront();

 BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
 worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
 worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted;
 worker.RunWorkerAsync(loading)
}

private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
 // Do your background-work here
 Thread.Sleep(10000);
 e.Result = e.Argument;
}

private void WorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
 LoadWindow loading= (LoadWindow)e.Result;
 loading.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tomtom!  I couldn't get the (LoadWindow)e.Result to work, so the only options I had were to make loading a global variable (bleah) or use al-amanat's suggestion and use a lambda.